# Finding a DOM element by attribute name and value using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, css-selectors

I am trying to find an anchor dom element which has attribute for example, href='/post/3534' by using document.querySelector and regex.

So something like,

```
document.querySelector("a[href='/post/(/[0-9]+/g)']")
```

but it obviously does not work.

What is the correct syntax for my purpose ? 
I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selectors don't accept regular expressions - the best you'll be able to do is `querySelectorAll` the `<a>`s, and then `.find` the one whose `href` matches your condition:

```js
const foundA = Array.prototype.find.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="/post/"]'),
  a => /^\/post\/[0-9]+/.test(a.getAttribute('href'))
);
if (foundA) {
  console.log(foundA.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

```html
<a href="foobar">foobar</a>
<a href="/post/words">words</a>
<a href="/post/1234">numbers</a>
```